# I want the user to only enter the item and once saved should not be editable except one field

Tags: client

I have created one list and I want the user to only enter the data and once saved , it should not be editable by the users except one field. Only admin can edit all the list items and user can only view. I am new to SharePoint. Can someone please help .

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this behavior is kind of complex for SharePoint. But you can create two lists, where one list have the field you want to update as a lookup column for the other list. On a workflow you can run on every new item which through web service calls breaks permission inheritance and set only admin with editor permission.

It works, but it's hard to come by. Why, may I ask, do you need this?